# MSSQL SELECT add custom row

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, row

Have this select. It generates list of users by team and sums they data. I need create custom row, it would be last row with all team sums, not by user. I have write select that will take that data, but I don't know how to add add it into all this select.

```
   SELECT 
        Drive.Owner 
        ,round(cast((sum(case when dock = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)+sum(case when dock = 'old' then 1 else 0 end))as float)/cast(count(dock)as float)*100,2) as ava
       ,round(cast(sum(case when dock = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)as float)/cast((sum(case when dock = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)+sum(case when dock = 'old' then 1 else 0 end))as float)*100,2) as uptodate
       ,ROUND(sum(case when firsta != 'none' then 1 else 0 end)/ROUND(CAST(count(firsta)AS FLOAT),2)*100,2) nones1
       ,ROUND(sum(case when seconda != 'none' then 1 else 0 end)/ROUND(CAST(count(seconda)AS FLOAT),2)*100,2) nones2
       ,ISNULL(ROUND(Sum(CAST(Ontime AS FLOAT))/Sum(task_count), 2),0) as ontime
       ,ISNULL(ROUND(AVG(CAST(actual AS FLOAT)), 2),0) as actual


FROM (
SELECT 
    users.user_name+ ' ' +users.user_surname AS Owner
    ,users.split as test
    ,sc.firstbackup as firsta
    ,sc.secondbackup as seconda
    ,sc.documentation as dock
    ,sc.active as active
    ,(SELECT CASE WHEN non_sc = '1' THEN 'regular' ELSE 'sc' END) as sc_or_non_sc
    FROM
    [bstplanning].[dbo].[sc]

INNER JOIN
    [bstplanning].[dbo].[users]
ON sc.user_id = users.user_id

WHERE
     users.split='Rep'
) Drive
left join
(
SELECT
     dbo.sc_data.track
    ,dbo.users.split
    ,dbo.sc_data.country
    ,dbo.sc_data.client
    ,dbo.sc_data.task_group
    ,MAX(ISNULL(dbo.users.user_name,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.users.user_surname,'')) as Owner
    ,AVG(CASE WHEN dbo.sc_data.ontime = 'on time' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END)*COUNT(dbo.sc_data.country) AS Ontime
    ,AVG(CASE WHEN dbo.sc_data.accuracy = 'accurate' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) AS actual
    ,COUNT(dbo.sc_data.country) AS task_count

FROM 
    [bstplanning].[dbo].[sc_data]

INNER JOIN dbo.users 
    ON dbo.sc_data.user_id = dbo.users.user_id  

WHERE
    dbo.sc_data.date >= '2016-06-01' AND dbo.sc_data.date <= '2016-06-15' AND   dbo.sc_data.actual > 0 AND
    ((dbo.sc_data.ontime='on time' OR dbo.sc_data.ontime = 'late') OR (dbo.sc_data.accuracy='accurate' OR dbo.sc_data.accuracy = 'error'))

GROUP BY
     dbo.sc_data.country
    ,dbo.sc_data.client
    ,dbo.sc_data.task_group
    ,dbo.users.split
    ,dbo.sc_data.track
    ) Drive2
    on Drive.Owner=Drive2.Owner
    where sc_or_non_sc ='sc'
    group by
    Drive.Owner
```

Code i need to add.

```
select 
round(cast((sum(case when aa.documentation = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)+sum(case when aa.documentation = 'old' then 1 else 0 end))as float)/cast(count(aa.documentation)as float)*100,2) as docas,
round(cast(sum(case when aa.documentation = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)as float)/cast((sum(case when aa.documentation = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end)+sum(case when aa.documentation = 'old' then 1 else 0 end))as float)*100,2) as uptodates

from dbo.sc aa , dbo.users bb

where bb.split='Rep' and bb.user_id=aa.user_id
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Could you try with an OVER on PARTITION which would aggregate the data in the same select call  .

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an
answer really needs a bit more detail than this.  Please
[edit] to explain how this will solve the problem.
Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.